# Oracle and C# - UDT array as return value

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to have C# read an array of a PL/SQL user defined type.

This is the definition of each object of the array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "REPORTDATUM" AS OBJECT
(
            FIELD1                                                   VARCHAR2(20),
            FIELD2                                                   VARCHAR2(3000),
            FIELD3                                                   NUMBER(15),
            FIELD4                                                   DATE,
            FIELD5                                                   DATE,
            FIELD6                                                   VARCHAR2(4000),
            FIELD7                                                   TIMESTAMP,
            FIELD8                                                   VARCHAR2(10),
            FIELD9                                                   NUMBER(35),
            FIELD10                                                  VARCHAR2(80),
            FIELD11                                                  VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "REPORTARRAY" IS TABLE OF REPORTDATUM;
```

This is the signature of the function which I am trying to call:

```
FUNCTION getReport(startTime IN DATE, endTime IN DATE) RETURN REPORTARRAY;
```

Now, based on a guide I found here: http://appsjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html

I created the ReportDatum.cs class as follows:

```
public class ReportDatum : INullable,  IOracleCustomType {

    private bool objectIsNull;

    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute(Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field1)]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute(Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field2)]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

                            [...]

    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute(Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field11)]
    public string Field11 { get; set; }


    public static ReportDatum Null {
        get {
            ReportDatum reportDatum = new ReportDatum();
            reportDatum.objectIsNull = true;
            return reportDatum;
        }
    }

    public bool IsNull {
        get { return objectIsNull; }
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, IntPtr userDefinedTypePointer) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Field1) == false ) {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field1, this.Field1);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Field2) == false) {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field2, this.Field2);
        }
        [...]
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Field11) == false) {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field11, this.Field11);
        }
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, IntPtr userDefinedTypePointer) {
        this.Field1 = parseString(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field1);
        this.Field2 = parseString(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field2);
                                            [...]
        this.Field11 = parseString(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, Constants.ReportDatum.Aliases.Field11);
    }

    private string parseString(OracleConnection databaseConnection, IntPtr userDefinedTypePointer, string columnName) {
        string valueToReturn = String.Empty;
        try {
            valueToReturn = ( String ) OracleUdt.GetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, columnName);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            error("Exception while attempting to parse string value of column [" + columnName + "]. Message [" + (e == null || e.Message == null ? "NULL" : e.Message) + "]", e);
        }
        return valueToReturn;
    }

 }
```

I've also proceeded to create ReportDatumFactory.cs as follows:

```
public class ReportDatumFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory {

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject() {
        return new ReportDatum();
    }

}
```

This, according to the guide I linked above should be sufficient to handle each item that composes the array.

In order to handle the array itself, I created the below classes.

ReportArray.cs

```
public class ReportArray : INullable, IOracleCustomType {

    [OracleArrayMapping()]
    public ReportDatum[] reportArray;

    private bool objectIsNull;

    public bool IsNull {
        get { return objectIsNull; }
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, IntPtr userDefinedTypePointer) {
        try {
            OracleUdt.SetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, 0, reportArray);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            error("Exception while populating OracleUdt from ReportArray.", e);
        }
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, IntPtr userDefinedTypePointer) {
        try {
            reportArray = ( ReportDatum[] ) OracleUdt.GetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            error("Exception while reading values from OracleUdt related to ReportArray.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

And the associated factory class

ReportArrayFactory.cs

```
public class ReportArrayFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory {

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject() {
        return new ReportArray();
    }


    public Array CreateArray(int numberOfElements) {
        return new ReportArray[numberOfElements];
    }

    public Array CreateStatusArray(int numberOfElements) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, in regards to the method that calls the stored procedure, this is what I have:

Report.cs

```
    private void executeStoredProcedure2(OracleConnection databaseConnection, string schema, string storedProcedureName, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, int numberOfElements) {
        OracleCommand databaseCommand = new OracleCommand();
        ReportArray reportArray = new ReportArray();

        debug("Attempting to populate the report array");
        if (databaseConnection != null && databaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
            try {
                databaseCommand.Connection = databaseConnection;
                databaseCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                databaseCommand.CommandText = schema + "." + storedProcedureName;
                databaseCommand.Parameters.Add(createUserDefinedParameter(numberOfElements, reportArray));
                databaseCommand.Parameters.Add(Constants.ReportDatum.ParameterNames.startTime, OracleDbType.Date, startTime, ParameterDirection.Input);
                databaseCommand.Parameters.Add(Constants.ReportDatum.ParameterNames.endTime, OracleDbType.Date, endTime, ParameterDirection.Input);
                databaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //How do I populate the reportArray object?
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
                error("Exception while executing stored procedure [" + storedProcedure2 + "].", exception);
            }
            finally {
                databaseCommand.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }



    private OracleParameter createUserDefinedParameter(int size, ReportArray reportArray) {
        OracleParameter valueToReturn = null;
        try {
            valueToReturn = new OracleParameter();
            valueToReturn.ParameterName = "reportData"; //this is the name of the REPORTARRAY object in the Oracle function that is being returned.
            valueToReturn.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
            valueToReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            valueToReturn.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            valueToReturn.UdtTypeName = Constants.ReportDatum.arrayDataTypeDefinition;
            valueToReturn.ArrayBindSize = new int[size];
            valueToReturn.ArrayBindStatus = new OracleParameterStatus[size];
            valueToReturn.Size = size;
            valueToReturn.Value = reportArray.reportArray;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            error("Exception while attempting to create user defined parameter.", e);
        }
        return valueToReturn;
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to obtain the array back in C#. Has anyone faced this problem? What am I missing?

I have reason to believe the SQL code is working. It's only the C# that is creating the problem at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There look to be a few things wrong.

Firstly, the factories need `OracleCustomTypeMapping` attributes.  Without them, Oracle won't pick up that these mapping factory classes should be used at all:

```
    [OracleCustomTypeMapping("SCHEMA.REPORTDATUM")]
    public class ReportDatum ...
```

and

```
    [OracleCustomTypeMapping("SCHEMA.REPORTARRAY")]
    public class ReportArray ...
```

Secondly, the array mapping factory has a bug in it: when creating an array, you want to create an array of `ReportDatum` objects.  At the moment you're creating an array of `ReportArray` objects, i.e. an array of arrays, which you don't want.  In other words, replace

```
    public Array CreateArray(int numberOfElements) {
        return new ReportArray[numberOfElements];
    }
```

with

```
    public Array CreateArray(int numberOfElements) {
        return new ReportDatum[numberOfElements];
    }
```

Thirdly, remove the line

```
        CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
```

from your `createUserDefinedParameter` method.  The returned value isn't a PL/SQL associative array (it's a different kind of collection) so this property should not be used.  If you use this property you will probably find that the return value coming back from the stored function is an empty `object` array.

Finally, to get the array back from the stored function call, add the following line after the call to `databaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`:

```
    reportArray = (ReportArray)databaseCommand.Parameters["reportData"].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This puts me a lot closer to my solution. Yes, you are correct in saying that before I was obtaining an empty object array. Now, however, I am getting the following exception: "Custom type mapping for 'dataSource='BLABLABLA' schemaName='XXXX' typeName='REPORTARRAY'' is not specified or invalid". However, when I run the same stored procedure from PL/SQL itself, it works...

Comment: I found the solution. On top of what you already indicated, I had to modify both the ReportDatumFactory.cs and the ReportArrayFactory.cs. In particular, I had to specify the OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute for both. For the former it's [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("SCHEMA.REPORTDATUM")], while for the latter it is [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("SCHEMA.REPORTARRAY")]. Once I did this, on top of what you indicated, I was able to get it to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @wasp1311: thanks for getting back to me, glad to hear you've got it working.  I've updated my answer to add the schema names to the type mapping attributes.  Missing those off was my fault: I got the code to work but I was connecting as the schema owner so Oracle didn't complain if I didn't qualify the types with their schema.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same approach and successfully executed Oracle SP (with custom table type OUT parameter) in VS app using C#.

**Oracle Query:**

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj as OBJECT(
         street VARCHAR2(20),
        city VARCHAR2(20),
          state CHAR(2),
          zip CHAR(5));

create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj_array IS TABLE OF test_obj;
```

[Refer to the data defined in EMP table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/356Jc.png)

*Stored Procedure:*

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE test_obj_procedure_array
(
    table_p OUT test_obj_array
 )
IS
BEGIN
     table_p := test_obj_array();
    table_p.extend(3);
    select address into table_p(1) from emp where empno = 101;
    select address into table_p(2) from emp where empno = 102;
    select address into table_p(3) from emp where empno = 101;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

**.NET Code:**

*TestObject.cs*

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("TESTUSER.TEST_OBJ")]
public class TestObject : IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, INullable
{
    private bool _isNull;

    [OracleObjectMapping("STREET")]
    public virtual string street { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("CITY")]
    public virtual string city { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("STATE")]
    public virtual string state { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("ZIP")]
    public virtual string zip { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get { return this._isNull; }
    }

    public static TestObject Null
    {
        get { return new TestObject { _isNull = true }; }
    }

    // Create object
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new TestObject();
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, object pointerUdt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "STREET", street);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "CITY", city);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "STATE", state);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "ZIP", zip);
    }


    public virtual void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, object pointerUdt)
    {
        street = OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "STREET").ToString();
        city = OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "CITY").ToString();
        state = OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "STATE").ToString();
        zip = OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "ZIP").ToString();
    }
}
```

*TestObjectArray.cs*

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;

namespace Test.Function
{
    [OracleCustomTypeMapping("TESTUSER.test_obj_array")]
    public class TestObjectArray : INullable, IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
    {

        [OracleArrayMapping()]
        public TestObject[] testObjectArray;

        private bool objectIsNull;

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return objectIsNull; }
        }

        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new TestObjectArray();
        }


        public Array CreateArray(int numberOfElements)
        {
            return new TestObject[numberOfElements];
        }

        public Array CreateStatusArray(int numberOfElements)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, object userDefinedTypePointer)
        {
            try
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, 0, testObjectArray);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //error("Exception while populating OracleUdt from ReportArray.", e);
            }
        }

        public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection databaseConnection, object userDefinedTypePointer)
        {
            try
            {
                testObjectArray = (TestObject[])OracleUdt.GetValue(databaseConnection, userDefinedTypePointer, 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //error("Exception while reading values from OracleUdt related to ReportArray.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Program.cs:*

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("User Id=XXXX;Password=XXX;Data Source=localhost,1521/XE;"))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            command.CommandText = "BEGIN test_obj_procedure_array(:table_p);END;";
                            command.BindByName = true;

                            var valueToReturn = command.CreateParameter();
                            valueToReturn.ParameterName = "table_p";
                            valueToReturn.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
                            valueToReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            valueToReturn.UdtTypeName = "test_obj_array";

                            command.Parameters.Add(valueToReturn);

                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();                           

                        }
                    }
```

Now, I moved a step ahead and created the nested custom-type tables in Oracle and further used it as OUT parameter in new Stored Procedure.

**Oracle Query:**

```
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj as OBJECT(
         street VARCHAR2(20),
        city VARCHAR2(20),
          state CHAR(2),
          zip CHAR(5));

create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj_array IS TABLE OF test_obj;

create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj_new as OBJECT(
         street VARCHAR2(20),
        city VARCHAR2(20),
          state CHAR(2),
          zip CHAR(5),
          array test_obj_array);

create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TYPE test_obj_new_array IS TABLE OF test_obj_new;
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_obj_procedure_new_array
(
    table_p OUT test_obj_new_array
 )
IS
BEGIN
    table_p := test_obj_new_array();
    table_p.extend(1);
    table_p(1):= test_obj_new('','','','', test_obj_array());
    table_p(1).array := test_obj_array();
    table_p(1).array.extend(3);    
    select address into table_p(1).array(1) from emp where empno = 101;
    select address into table_p(1).array(2) from emp where empno = 102;
    select address into table_p(1).array(3) from emp where empno = 101;
END;
```

***Now I don't understand that how mapping will be further changed in TestObject.cs class to incorporate the new custom type(table of tables)?***